# C# Regex specify allowed start and end condtions

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regex expression with the following requirements:

The value:

1. Must start with `a-z` or `_`, numbers are OK after the first character
2. Can have parentheses if they are opened and closed with number inside at the end of string, i.e **SomeVar(10)** is OK, **SomeVar(10** is not OK.
3. Can have a `.` but only one at a time, and only between letters or numbers. **SomeVar.InnerVar** is OK, **SomeVar..Innevar** is not OK.

My try at the regex:

1. `[a-zA-Z_]`
2. ??
3. ??

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to match an entire string, you may use something like the following:

```
^[a-zA-Z_](?:\w|(?<=\w)\.(?=\w))*(?:\(\d+\))?$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bx1o9j/1)**.

If you want to match partial strings, you'd need to decide what boundaries are allowed. Otherwise, "SomeVar(10" would have a match (i.e., what comes before `(`), for example.

**Notes:**

- `\w` matches a lowercase/uppercase letter, a digit, or an underscore. But it also matches Unicode letters and numbers. If you don't want that, you could use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead.
- Similarly, `\d` matches any Unicode digit. You either use it or use `[0-9]` depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*(\([^()]*\))?$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/gHnO5X/1).

1. `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` - a letter or underscore, then zero or more letters, digits, underscores
2. `(\([^()]*\))?` - optional group, parens may be present or absent
3. `(\.[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)*` - dot is allowed between letter/digit/underscore.